# How to Cut Sensor Filter Glass?

Tags: sensor

Context - I've modified my Sony A7S for astrophotography by removing LPF2. Upon doing so, I've found that my lenses no longer achieve focus at or near infinity (they're older A-mount manual lenses). I understand that adding a piece of clear low-reflectivity glass in place of LPF2 will work. I measured LPF2 thickness as 1.5mm, but I can only find 1mm or 2mm thick glass - presumably 2mm thick will push the infinity point further down the scale, so this is my preference. I'm based in Australia, so postage from the US is very expensive.

Problem - I've found glass that appears to be suitable from Edmund Optics, but they only supply 50x50mm pieces of glass but I need it cut to suit the sensor (30x41.6mm). Edmund Optics advised they have a MOQ of 20 for custom cutting. The glass is expensive - ~AUD200 a piece, so I want to make sure I have a robust method before attempting. So far, I haven't found any suggestions online that give me the confidence I want.

Proposal - I am considering 3D Printing a jig of sorts - one that would allow me to 'clamp' the glass (with some soft facing to avoid scratching) for work holding. It would also provide the finished dimensions. I think I would then use sandpaper (mounted to a flat surface) to gently sand down to the appropriate size. It would take a long while, but I'm reluctant to use any tools that require force or power tools. I imagine one wrong move and a crack could propagate very easily.

Alternatives - LifePixel offers the correct size glass, but it costs about AUD480 inc freight to Australia, so I'd like to find cheaper alternatives.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered having a local glass cutting/supply shop cut it for you? Probably worth a phone call anyway.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the precise glass cuts are done with fluids with maybe some abrasive additives..

Comment: There are shops that will do such cutting for you. I believe straight cuts are usually done with a diamond disk saw. You could do worse than searching here: https://www.photonics.com/Buyers_Guide/Optical_Assemblies/ca48450

Comment: All helpful suggestions. Thanks

Comment: a sanding attachment for an oscillating tool would work a lot faster than hand-sanding, without the additional mechanical risk imposed by a random orbit or belt sander; it just swipes back and forth a few mm 100s of times a second. You'll want to work on each side for a short while then rotate and repeat often so as to spread out the heat.

Comment: I have ordered a Chinese knock-off piece of glass (similar dimensions) for AU$30, it will let me trial a few solutions before risking the expensive option.
A small power tool like an oscillating tool or perhaps a rotary tool might be a good option.